# AMD Adrenaline how to disable "Now Recording" notification

Tags: technical-issues, recording

**How can I turn off this notification?**

[image: annoying toaster notification]

I am using AMD Radeon Software to record a video. Unfortunately at the start of the video brief toaster notification is shown. This is pretty annoying as I have to cut first 3 sec of every video I make in order to remove the toaster.